# Forgot dd-wrt router password

Tags: router, dd-wrt

I have flashed my Netgear 6400 with dd-wrt firmware and have made a configuration that reset button is disabled. However, I forget the original password after a few days. Are there any ways I can reset the password or get back the original password? Thank you very much.

Comment: [DD-WRT Wiki: Reset And Reboot](https://wiki.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Reset_And_Reboot) those are your options. If they're not available to you (anymore) you probably will have to remember the password.

Comment: The problem is that the I forgot the password. So I am finding ways to erase the NVRAM

Comment: Well you did disable the button that is meant to do the very thing. So in all likely hood you won't be able to do it without changing hardware and got yourself a nice paperweight unless you remember that password. You could also try whenever that button is actually disabled during boot and not "just" after the system comes up.

Answer (score 1):

You need to get it into recovery mode so you can reflash, and it will be back to default settings.

Here's how:

1. Power the router off.
2. Press and hold the reset button and turn the power on.
3. Wait for the router to go into “Upgrade Mode” about 15 seconds, and release the
   reset button. (The power LED become white and blinks steadily)
4. Use tftp32 to put dd-wrt or the original firmware back on the router.

Good luck, don't disable the reset button in the future!